# Firebase Dynamic Links redirecting to App Store/Play Store instead of opening app directly from browser search bar

Tags: flutter, firebase, deep-linking, flutter-deep-link

I'm facing an issue with Firebase Dynamic Links. When the dynamic link is opened from a browser's search bar, it redirects the user to the App Store/Play Store instead of opening the app directly. I'm looking for a solution where I can open the app directly instead of redirecting to the store.

Here's the context: I have an admin web portal and a corresponding mobile app. I'm sending out a WhatsApp campaign, and depending on whether the link is opened on a desktop or a mobile device, I want to redirect the user to the web or the app respectively. However, the app link deep link is currently opening the App Store/Play Store.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to handle this situation effectively.
Thank you in advance for your help!

[Ref Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnJvq.png)

1. Is there anyway I can override this behaviour?
2. What is the best way (packages, methods, flows) to build a inhouse deeplink handler?

Comment: still surviving..

Comment: used app_links (https://pub.dev/packages/app_links)